# counting a sequence of item, python

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

The task is to define a function `count_vowels(text)` that takes a string `text`, counts the
vowels in text (using a Python dictionary for the counting), and returns the
vowel frequency information as a string.
Example:

```
>>> count_vowels('count vowels')
'e: 1\nu: 1\no: 2'
>>> print count_vowels('count vowels')
e: 1
u: 1
o: 2
```

so far I've come up with:

```
>>> def count_vowels(text):
    counts = nltk.defaultdict(int)
    for w in text:
        if w in 'aeoiu':
            counts[w] += 1
    return counts


>>> count_vowels('count vowels')
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'e': 1, 'u': 1, 'o': 2})
```

so, what's wrong with my code and how do I get the same result as in the example?

Comment: Python has a built-in `collections.defaultdict`. Using `nltk.defaultdict` is a bit obscure and confusing.

Comment: Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.

Comment: Short answer: Your `count_vowels()` function is returning a `nltk.defaultdict(int)` instance not a string. You need to add code to the end of your function to return one based on what ends up in the `defaultdict` and formatted the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
return '\n'.join( '%s: %s' % item for item in counts.items())
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer here that returns the string as requested!

Comment: Thx S.Lott, I missed a space, 3 is not 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.7, try using a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(c for c in 'count vowels' if c in 'aeoiu')
for k, v in counts.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

This results in the output:

```
e 1
u 1
o 2
```

If you have an earlier version of Python, you can still use your defaultdict, and just use the same `iteritems()` loop:

```
for k, v in counts.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is the same. Are you referring to how the result is formatted? Write some code at the end of the function that converts the resulting dictionary into a string in the right format.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
def count_vowels(text):
vowels = 'aeiou'
counts ={}
s = ''
for letter in text:
    if letter in vowels:
        if letter in counts:
            counts[letter] += 1
        else:
            counts[letter] = 1
for item in counts:
    s = s + item + ': ' + str(counts[item]) + '\n'
return s[:-1]
```

This outputs:

```
>>> count_vowels('count vowels')
'e: 1\nu: 1\no: 2'
>>> print count_vowels('count vowels')
e: 1
u: 1
o: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you're returning the entire dictionary of an integer type, I think. Try iterating through the dictionary and printing each key to format it like you want.